# Inline entity form: Allow add existing nodes only for specific node types and node author

Tags: 8

I use the "complex widget" of the inline entity form (IEF) module.
The user should be able to create new nodes of a specific type and also add already existing nodes with the field form.

**My problem:**

When the user adds an already existing node (entity) I found no way to limit the referenced entities yet. There appears a select list with the node content type and then the user can choose every node.

I want to limit the choice by

- only a specific node content type **and**
- only showing nodes of this content type where the current user is the author.

Is there a possibility to limit the choice perhaps by a view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In general you can restrict the content type in the field settings and restrict the nodes for the current user by access, independently from the widget you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I restrict the allowed node types via a reference view. But the "complex widget" with "add existing nodes" are showing in the select list all content types the user has access to.